# views result not showing to authenticated users

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am calling a view on users profile page that lists all articles with status draft =1.

This view code i've entered in user-profile.tpl file

```
  <?php
    $view = views_get_view('drafts', true);
    $view->set_display('default');
    print "<h2>". $view->get_title(). "</h2>";
    $view->pre_execute();
    $view->execute();
    print $view->render('default');
  ?>
```

Now if i see this page from users/admin it shows the result but when i log in from another account which is authenticated. It just shows the Title of View. I have confired the permissions of views and its fine. I set it to role = authenticated

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show user profile data, make sure that `authenticated user` role has the permission `view user profiles`.

Comment: You mean user cannot see his own profile ? is this possible ?